# slide effect of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have been having this problem with a slide effect of jQuery, the effect I want to get is as you click on the question the answer slides down. It is working for the first one, but isn't for the next few questions. Here is a link to the example http://jsfiddle.net/p8CLN/3/ 
`$(document).ready(function(){
              $("#question").click(function(){
                $("#answer").slideToggle("slow");
              });
            });`
I have really been stumped on this one.

Comment: You're not supposed to have more than one occurrence for each ID.

Comment: ID's are unique, voting to close as duplicate of ten thousand others!

Comment: @Terry you're not *allowed* to have more than one occurrence for each ID.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. But what would be the easiest way to solve the problem for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert all your IDs to classes, and give the click function a context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".question").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

See updated fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/p8CLN/8/

Comment: Thanks terry this solved my problems and was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Yes thanks I will I can only accept it in 6 min though

Answer (score 0):

IDs MUST be unique.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p8CLN/5/) is an updated Fiddle. I have replaced the IDs with a class name and used `.next()` to get the appropriate answer element.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using multiple elements with id's of `question` and `answer`.  Id's MUST be unique as jquery will stop building a collection after the first id it finds.

I have updated your fiddle to fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/p8CLN/6/

Note I also needed to change CSS and added a use `next('.answer')` to target the toggle only to the subsequent answer to the clicked question.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".question").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle("slow");
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you provide same id for the multiple elements.
the ids must be unique.
once the document is ready.
on document.ready you can bind a click event
you can use the next as a solution.
here is the example

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".question").click(function()
{
$(this).next(".answer).slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```